# picture not uploading into database with polymorphic association with carrier wave in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 3.1.0 and rails 7.0.4, I have created user, post and image models, providing relations between all of them. image and post model has a polymorphic association, create post scaffold

relations of the user, post and image model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :posts
  
end
```

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  validates :title, :description, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

end
```

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
    require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    mount_uploader :image_url, AvatarUploader

end
```

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.images.build
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: "Post was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: "Post was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: "Post was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, images_attributes: [:id, :image_url])
    end
end
```

app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: post) do |form| %>
    <% if post.errors.any? %>
        <div style="color: red">
            <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %>
                prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
                <% post.errors.each do |error| %>
                    <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div>
        <%= form.label :title, style: "display: block" %>
        <%= form.text_field :title %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= form.label :description, style: "display: block" %>
        <%= form.text_field :description %>
    </div>

    <%= form.fields_for :images do |image| %>
        <div>
            <%= image.label :image_url, style: "display: block" %>
            <%= image.file_field :image_url, multiple: true %>
        </div>
    <% end %>


    <div>
        <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

app/gemfile.rb

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"
  gem "pry"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end

gem "figaro"
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 2.0'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'file_validators'

gem 'devise'
```

app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

The selected image is not inserted into the database, please help me.

thanks!

Comment: Can you please error log and request params in the questions ?

Comment: not getting any error in rails log and no error showing in the network tab, request params is   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, images_attributes: [:id, :image_url])

Comment: can you add actual parameters passed to action. like {post: {title: 'Abc'.......}}

Comment: I have tried the parameter you suggested but it's still giving the same result, getting a nil value in the database in place of the image_url attribute.

Comment: I have just removed multiple: true attribute from file_field helper, it's working fine for me as i expected.